# MySQL Join with Grouping and Ordering

Tags: mysql, join

Im trying to do a LEFT JOIN/INNER JOIN/JOIN (forgot the differences, my MySQL knowledge got dusty...) on two tables. one is `categories` and the other is `images` .

I want to return a list of all `categories` with a certain `parent` value, and for each of these categories return the latest image from `images` for that category.

I ended up with this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `categories` AS `a`
         JOIN (SELECT `im`.`preview` AS `preview`,
                      `im`.`cid` AS `cid` 
               FROM `images` AS `im`
               ORDER BY `im`.`cid` DESC) AS `b`
               ON (`a`.`cid` = `b`.`cid`)
         GROUP BY `preview`
```

This returns a single image from the images table for each row in the category table, 
But if I'd try to condition/sort the resulting table, I'll start getting weird results, 
for example changing the end to this or any similar variation:

```sql
WHERE `a`.`parent` = 10
GROUP BY `preview`
ORDER BY `a`.`cid
```

Would appreciate any ideas you would have on this. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Peter's answer already helped me resolved the issue , but thank you very much Mahmoud !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it also without join, just using subselect:

```
SELECT
c.*,
(SELECT preview 
 FROM images img 
 WHERE img.cid = c.cid 
 ORDER BY img.id DESC
 LIMIT 1) AS preview
FROM categories c
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks :) I always get confused about when to use JOIN or not.